# How to identify the prediction equation from a regression model using splines

Tags: r, interpretation, splines, rms

I find it difficult to connect the coefficients of a regression model that includes splines to the actual prediction equation. For example, how could that be done with the following model?

```
> library(rms)
> x <- 1:11
> y <- c(0.2,0.40, 0.6, 0.75, 0.88, 0.99, 1.1, 1.15, 1.16, 1.16, 1.16 )
> dd <- datadist(x); options(datadist='dd')
>  f <- ols(y ~ rcs(x, c(3, 5, 7, 9)))
> f  


  Linear Regression Model

ols(formula = y ~ rcs(x, c(3, 5, 7, 9)))

            Model Likelihood     Discrimination    
               Ratio Test           Indexes        
Obs       11    LR chi2     66.08    R2       0.998    
sigma 0.0201    d.f.            3    R2 adj   0.996    
d.f.       7    Pr(> chi2) 0.0000    g        0.383    

Residuals

  Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.027360 -0.011739  0.001227  0.009892  0.031166 

           Coef    S.E.   t     Pr(>|t|)
Intercept  0.0465 0.0224  2.08 0.0762  
x          0.1741 0.0072 24.18 <0.0001 
x'        -0.1004 0.0311 -3.23 0.0144  
x''        0.0542 0.0913  0.59 0.5715  


> Function(f)
function(x = 6){
  0.046475489 + 0.17411942*x - 0.002790266*pmax(x-3,0)^3 + 
  0.0015048699*pmax(x-5,0)^3 + 0.0053610582*pmax(x-7,0)^3 - 
  0.0040756621*pmax(x-9,0)^3 
}
```

Comment: (To whom it may concern: although this question is asked in terms of R, I think it has enough statistical content to be considered on topic here.)

Comment: 1. `ols` is not a function that comes with R; neither is `rcs`. If I paste your code it in would not run. Presumably you're using the package `rms`, but you should state so explicitly rather than leaving people to guess.  $\:$ 2. It looks like your question is already answered at the bottom of your code -- `Function(f)` produces the equation you seem to be asking for right there in your output; an equation directly in terms of splines. What were you seeking that's different from that?

Comment: Sorry that i did not mention that the package rms was used before. My question was how that final equation was derived from the coefficients of the regression model? The coefficients of the regression model and those in the final equation are not same, so wondering how to get those numbers.